# Highlight for Current Menu Item not highlighting correctly

Tags: menu, highlight

I would like the current menu item to stay highlighted when a user is in that section. I set up styles for .current-menu-item. For some reason some styles work and some don't. I used all of these for testing purposes:

```
.current-menu-item {
    color:#F90;
    border-bottom:2px solid #fco;
    text-decoration:line-through;
        background:#000;
}
```

Background and Text-Decorationare the only styles that work. Any clues why the others do not? I really only want the text color to stay orange (highlighted #f90).

Thanks in advance for any help :)

sandra :)

Comment: Try http://www.hicksdesign.co.uk/else/cssnav/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Your color rule is likely being overridden by a more specific rule. You can investigate this further, using 'Inspect Element' in google chrome, and looking at the styles in the inspector.